# ac current measured in a 3 phase dc rectifier

Tags: dc, rectifier

Hi have a 3 phase DC rectifier: input 400V AC; output up to 10V/2000A DC

I'm aware that it's normal to have some AC current in the output of the rectifier and in this particular case it is acceptable up to 5% Ripple.

However something odd is happening. Once the rectifier is ON without any load, i'm getting close to 0V AC in the + output terminal (which is good), but i'm getting 6 to 9V AC in the - output terminal.

What could be the problem? What should i be looking at?

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously you have more than just a rectifier. Show us a complete diagram, and also explain exactly how you're making these measurements.

Comment: If you have no isolation then the negative terminal will be at some voltage opposed to the positive terminal around the real or virtual star point.  The fact that + and - are not of the same magnitude means you do not have the start point as reference, we need more input to assist.  You can look for ideas here -  https://www.google.fi/search?q=ripple+on+3phase+rectified+dc&tbm=isch

Comment: it's something like this http://www.reliablepowersystem.com/prd/dc-power-supply1.jpg. i'm measuring what comes out from the wide metallic bars + and -

Answer (score 1):

Full wave and unfiltered rectified 3 phase looks like this: -

[image]

So unless you use an output capacitor to smooth things out you will get a ripple voltage as shown in red.

Comment: if DC is 0V, shouldn't AC be also 0V?

Comment: @Reznik the DC output should be close to the peak of the 3 phase AC supply. The AC content of the DC level will be a few volts as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

Bulk storage cap is still needed to filter the AC with a Rload//ESR*C=T time constant to compute the LPF attenuation at 6f.

DC Load regulation still depends on [ESR(f)@Ipeak: {diodes(2R)+cap(f)} /Z_load.

2000A load with low load regulation demands peak currents >> 2kA but still better than single phase, where Ipk=Irms/% ripple

Comment: sorry, my knowledge is limited in this subject. What you said is applicable if DC is 0V? Because that's what happening. DC is 0V and AC in negative terminal is 6 to 9V.

Comment: No, but, If using a DMM, yes both AC and DC measurements use the same common terminal (-)